# Subquery returning more than 1 value in below query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi all am facing issue in below query. I have three fields where Customer_id is the ID of a customer, GUID is a global identifier of a customer and there is DB_Parentid field where it holds the value of parent customer of customer(like parent company of another company).

Here am trying to populate the GUID field in the 'Customer Guid field' using the below sub query. Below query runs fine for 255 rows from 49 k records. Same query is working for another customer table.

```
select 

Customer_id as'SourceSystemID',

GUID as 'CustomerGUID',

(select a1.Customer_id from Customer a left join Customer a1 on a.DB_PARENT_ID=a1.Customer_id where a.Customer_id=Customer.Customer_id) AS 'Customer ParentGUID'

FROM dbo.Customer
```

Comment: What problem you having here

Comment: Try asking a question.

Comment: CustomerParentGUID genereted where it uses the DB_Parent_ID in the Source System to locate the parent account record and get the CustomerGUID from that record

Comment: You need to use aggregate (max()) or top 1 in your subquery to return just single result.

Comment: @Arvo top 1 seems to be working but it just taking time... any help to make query execution faster

Comment: @Arvo Max() function worked well!!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing a join inside the subquery?  I think your intention should be to just correlate it to the outer query:

```
select Customer_id as SourceSystemID,
       GUID as CustomerGUID,
       (select parent.Customer_id
        from Customer parent 
        where c.DB_PARENT_ID = parent.Customer_id
       ) AS "Customer ParentGUID"
FROM dbo.Customer c;
```

I also think the original formulation may have had the logic backwards, returning the children rather than the parent.

Finally, you would more typically do this with a `left outer join`:

```
select Customer_id as SourceSystemID,
       GUID as CustomerGUID,
       parent.Customer_id AS "Customer ParentGUID"
FROM Customer c left outer join
     Customer parent
     on c.DB_PARENT_ID = parent.Customer_id
```

Comment: AM using join query to genereate the customer parentguid

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.Customer_id as'SourceSystemID',
a.GUID as 'CustomerGUID',
a1.Customer_id  AS 'Customer ParentGUID'
FROM dbo.Customer a
left join Customer a1 on a.DB_PARENT_ID=a1.Customer_id
```